# wget with 304 check

Tags: wget, curl

Is it possible to use wget to download a file, if only it's not modified?

I'm thinking about the HTTP status code 304, but I don't know how to instruct wget to add a `If-Modified-Since` header, or something similar.

Is it even possible? I can use other tools to do that as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may wish to read this,  http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/wget_5.html

Basically, it's :

```
wget -N http://www.some-url.com/folder/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a header, you can use [the `--header` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html):

```
wget --header="If-Modified-Since: …" http://example.com/
```

But for the specific case in the question, it’s better to do as the other answer here suggests: Just use the `-N` option.